# Illustrator exporting SVG, viewbox doesn't match artboard size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, artboard

I'm attempting to output an SVG from Illustrator. My artboard is 256x256 pixels. The top left of the artboard is at 0,0.

When I export my svg, the `viewbox` attribute is `0.5 792.5 256 256`. Why isn't it `0 0 256 256`?

All layers/paths/etc are within the 256x256 box. Nothing is outside of it.

Also, I just created a fresh 256x256 document and copy/pasted all my layers from the old file to the new one and the viewbox was `0 0 256 256` as expected. So what was it about the original file that was throwing in that offset in the `viewbox`?

Update: I just deleted all the layers except for one, and exported. The viewbox is now: `0.5 536.5 256 256`, which still doesn't make sense. Especially since the artboard is empty now.

Here is the AI file if you want to look:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0u6r46b3j9sefa/sprites-old.ai?dl=0

Comment: post the .ai, if possible. the graphics are irrelevant, you can remove them. ill try to enlighten you, to the best of my abilities.

Comment: I updated the question with a link to the .ai file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

there's nothing wrong with the .ai you provided. i looked at it, spotted nothing wrong, I tried different export options, even resizing the artboard and moving it around.

I did some reading and it turns out Adobe did a half job when it included svg support. Adobe does not use svg viewboxes and offers no way to actually define a viewboxes coordinates.

What you experienced usually happens when you drag / resize artboards on a document. A number of people found themselves facing this issues and the only workaround seems to be exactly what you did. File -> New.

Another fix would be importing the svgs in Inkscape and exporting from there. But I think the file new is way faster.

I'm sorry I can't help you more, it's really up to Adobe to fix this.

PS: This question has some good [answers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15401/change-viewbox-attribute-in-svg-exported-by-illustrator).

Comment: That seems to be the conclusion I have come up with as well. Thank you!