# Weird layer export on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, layers, export

I'm using `Illustrator CC`.

I select a layer, which is 16x44 pixels:

[image]

Than I right click, Export, and I save it on `SVG`. That't the result:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="5.64444mm" height="15.52222mm" viewBox="0 0 16 44">
  <title>Slider</title>
  <g id="Livello_2" data-name="Livello 2">
    <g id="Slider">
      <g id="Background">
        <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="15" height="43" fill="#a09f9f"/>
        <path d="M15,1V43H1V1H15m1-1H0V44H16V0Z" fill="#231f20"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Some weirdness:

1. what are `<title>Slider</title>` and `<g id="Livello_2" data-name="Livello 2">`? They aren't on layers. Can I remove it?
2. It places `width="5.64444mm" height="15.52222mm" viewBox="0 0 16 44"`, which mess the dimensions. Can I remove that "scaling"? I don't want it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Livello" is Italian for layer.  In my UK English version of AI, it appears as `<g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">`

However the tag `<g id>` is only a group id, not a layer as such. So, you can just remove the tag if you want. Obviously you mustn't forget to also remove the relevant `</g>` tag

Here's an example showing two rectangles, deleting the `<g id="Layer_2" data name="Layer 2"`, and renaming the other group IDs.  I'm using Notepad++ for editing the XML.

[image]

**Edit:**  After comments from the OP, and a little more research it would seem there is a better way to export an SVG rather than using Export Selection.  Using *Export As* seems to give less quirky results, with no manual editing required.

Anyway, here's what I did

- Click *Object > Artboards > Fit to Artwork Bounds*.
  This will rescale the artboard to fit the artwork.
- Click *File > Export > Export As*, choose SVG as the file format,
  then hit *Export*
- The SVG export dialog will appear. Click OK

[image]

Here's the XML output without any manual editing. It's pretty clean, with no Illustrator weirdness.

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 136 325">
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{fill:#bcbec0;stroke:#231f20;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:6px;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>Untitled-1</title>
    <rect class="cls-1" x="3" y="3" width="130" height="319"/>
</svg>
```

The difference between the viewbox and object dimensions is simply due to the size of the stroke. If there were no stroke, the viewbox and object dimensions would be identical. Also note that in the SVG export dialog you could set the Object IDs to "minimal" - which will get rid of the `<SVG id="Layer>` nonsense, which is unnecessary.

Comment: But on Illustrator I don't have any "layer" above "Slider". Why it adds it? And no, I don't want to manually edit every export, obviously.

Comment: @markzzz I don't know why Illustrator uses "Layer_2" in the group id, or why it even adds that group at all, since it's not necessary.  But it's not actually a layer anyway, just Illustrator's weird way of doing things.

Comment: ok. What about that "scaling". It doesn't export the same size. I have AI CC 2019

Comment: I think that's useful https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39505/illustrator-exporting-svg-viewbox-doesnt-match-artboard-size/39535#39535

Comment: @markzzz - see my edit now.

Comment: It seems I don't need "Click Object > Artboards > Fit to Artwork Bounds. This will rescale the artboard to fit the artwork.". Just select only the object on the layer panel, and Export will automatically fit the exported section. Not sure how to remove the <title> tag anywy, it still keep on the svg exported...